# Leaflet/Mapbox Markers Don't Repeat After Scrolling Around the Atlas

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Screenshot from [Mapbox docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/fit-map-to-markers/):
[image: Mapbox screenshot]

It seems as though Mapbox won't render given coordinates multiple times on the same map, even if the map is zoomed out far enough to view the same latitude and longitude pairing twice. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Markers do not appear on continuous world in Leaflet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632608/markers-do-not-appear-on-continuous-world-in-leaflet)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `worldCopyJump` option of `L.mapbox.map` (`L.map`):

> With this option enabled, the map tracks when you pan to another "copy" of the world and seamlessly jumps to the original one so that all overlays like markers and vector layers are still visible.

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cbDNH6Rs5SbBKGY7LQGe?p=preview

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-worldcopyjump