# Markers do not appear on continuous world in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When I set option `continuousWorld=true` markers are not shown on the cloned tiles, only on the main world. Is it designed behavior? May be other option, which I haven't noticed, to show these markers exists?

**UPD:** My aim to repeat markers on every world like on the picture below.
I investigated that `continuousWorld` and `worldcopyjump` are not suitable for this. So is this possible to make leaflet work as on the picture? 
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no automatic and out-of-the-box solution that I know of that would copy all content (markers, vectors, etc.) on adjacent copies of the world in Leaflet.

The easiest trick as proposed by Tomislav would be to manually generate extra copies of your content, offset by multiples of 360 degrees longitude. I think the `continuousWorld` tileLayer option **must be left at `false`** for that. In conjunction with `worldCopyJump` map option, you could achieve the desired effect, at the expense of having to clone your content several times.

That being said, this may be just 1 possible solution for your objective, which you have not really explicited?

If you want to avoid the user from seeing an empty world, maybe you could simply not show the adjacent copies of the world. You have several ways of achieving that, and you can use them in conjunction:

- [`noWrap` tileLayer option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-nowrap) to not display adjacent copies.
- [`maxBounds` map option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds) to clamp panning to 1 world boundaries (or any other specified bounds).
- [`minZoom` map option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-minzoom) to prevent zooming out too much so that there is no room in the view port for several copies of the world.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/20/

Note: if `minZoom` is set high enough, the use of [`worldCopyJump` map option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-worldcopyjump) renders a very similar effect as in Google Maps, i.e. you think you are rolling all around the world and find your content again. It is just that you never have a chance to see the exact same location twice on the same screen, and that the map automatically rolls back 360 degrees to remain on the content. This is still noticeable at the -180 / +180 degrees longitude border, as you have either content on the left or on the right, but never both simultaneously.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/21/

Answer (score 3):

When using continuous world and want to markers to appear on other "copies" of the map you should set coordinates of that marker to coordinates of that "world".

Only "central" world has coordinates in range -180 to 180 and -90 to 90

So for the world to the right longitude would start at 180 for that worlds -180.
Similar to other sides.

Basically you can add a new marker with longitude increased/decreased by 360 degrees for each "copy".

Comment: If I work directly with google maps the behavior is different, right? Google maps range is  -180 to 180 and and -90 to 90 only.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I was looking for the same answer recently and managed to pull something that works pretty well. This is the function I was able to make:

```
const fitsBounds = (pos) => {
  const visibleBounds = map.getBounds();
  const west = visibleBounds.getWest();
  const east = visibleBounds.getEast();

  let flag = visibleBounds.contains(pos);

  const initialPos = L.latLng([pos.lat, pos.lng]);

  if (!flag) {
    if (west < -180) {
      const d = parseInt((west - 180) / 360);
      pos.lng += 360 * d;
      flag = visibleBounds.contains(pos);
      if (d < -1 && !flag) { // this part it hard to explain for me so easiest thing to do to understand how it work is to remove it and go far past 180
        pos = initialPos;
        pos.lng += 360 * (d + 1);
        flag = visibleBounds.contains(pos);
      }
    } else if (east > 180) {
      const d = parseInt((east + 180) / 360);
      pos.lng += 360 * d;
      flag = visibleBounds.contains(pos);
      if (d > 1 && !flag) {
        pos = initialPos;
        pos.lng += 360 * (d - 1);
        flag = visibleBounds.contains(pos);
      }
    }
  }

  return [flag, pos];
};
```

Usage:

```
   const lat = pilot["latitude"]; //example data (need to be separated from marker position and be between +-180)
    const long = pilot["longitude"]; //example data
    const inBounds = fitsBounds(L.latLng(lat, long));
    if (inBounds[0]) {
      createMarker(pilot, inBounds[1]);
    }
```

The `createMarker` function makes a marker, adds the data from the pilot object to the marker to separate marker coordinates from pilot coordinates, and adds it to the map.

If you have any questions please ask because my explanation skills are not at a high level. I hope this helps