# Leaflet - markers in continuousWorld WITHOUT changing longitudinal points?

Tags: leaflet, latitude-longitude, cartography

In reference to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632608/markers-do-not-appear-on-continuous-world-in-leaflet) I would like to know: 
Using leaflet, is it possible to draw markers in multiple adjacent worlds(leaflet's continuousWorld) WITHOUT adjusting their longitudes?

Please understand, I don't want to use leaflet's [worldcopyjump](http://embed.plnkr.co/mWKc4M/) as it does not show markers in multiple worlds simultaneously.

A workaround is to change longitudes by 360 degrees (-900 to -540, -540 to -180 etc. to one side and 180 to 540, 540 to 900 etc. to the other side) while maintaining latitudes.

Apparently, leaflet does not offer automated marker repeat due to ["performance concerns"](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1945) (Quote from 2013). Yet, Google Maps offer this.

With a practical view to resolve this problem, I see two solutions and I'd appreciate comments on this:

1. Use Google visualization instead
2. Copy my list of nodes a few times each direction and adjust their longitudes (this is assuming the conventional consumer would not keep drag-droping the world ca. two-three times around)

Many thanks in advance,
Naibaf

Comment: Just a note regarding your solution 2: combined with `wordcopyjump`, you would just need a few adjacent copies (enough to fill your map at minimum zoom) and your user should never have an empty map whatever the extent of panning.

Comment: Thanks, but why use worldcopyjump at all in what you propose? If my understanding is correct, worldcopyjumps replicates the layer of 180 to -180 across -540 to -180 and so forth WHILST removing the layer from 180 to -180 or the previously present range when crossing its range threshold. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: It seems to me that this option does not replicate anything, but changes the view back to [-180; 180] without the user noticing it. Give it a try.